# Forward request from host to host

Tags: macos, port-forwarding

We have a Snow Leopard Mac, play Warcraft 3 and the router is an Asus RT-G32.

Situation is so: The task is to forward requests going to `europe.battle.net` to another IP address. I have no idea how to do it in OS X. The question is – how to spoof DNS name (or IP), and change it to another?

Hosts file has no luck :(

Man, it's not working (ip is europe.battle.net ip):

```
new gateway ip    213.248.106.65
new gateway ip    213.248.106.66
new gateway ip    213.248.106.67
new gateway ip    213.248.106.68
new gateway ip    213.248.106.200
new gateway ip    213.248.106.201
new gateway ip    213.248.106.202
```

no result :( - it still address to europe.battle.net

Comment: "very stupid, very unclean"... I like the disclaimer :)  I wish I knew the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the host file on you system. You can find the instructions [here](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/).

Edit the `/private/etc/hosts` file.

Add a line the the file in such a manner:

`New IP(or host)` `Old IP(or host)`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```